# PDO count row values based on WHERE

Tags: php, math, pdo, count, sum

I looked over PHPDelusions website few times before asking this, as well as used Google but I still can't seem to get the code to work, or find a solution that remotely mirrors my question in general.

I made a super simple PHP7 script for managing Receipts. The fields are simple.

```
id (int 12), amount (varchar 8), category (int 2), date (date)
```

The problem I'm facing is I'm trying to **Count** the **Total Amount** of money based on **Categories**. So let's say **Category = 1** would count all Amounts with that respective category and so on.

Here is my existing code.

```
function getAmountCount(PDO $pdo, $cat) {

    $data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `receipts` WHERE category = :cat_id");
    $data->bindValue(':cat_id', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $data->execute();
    $result = $data->fetchColumn();

    echo money_format('%(#10n', $result['amount']).' CAD';

}

#and here is how we call it in the script
echo getAmountCount($pdo, 1);
```

The current code returns: **$ 0.00 CAD**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, to get the total amount of money for each category, you should be using `SUM`, not `COUNT`. `COUNT` will simply return a count of the number of rows associated with that category. Secondly, [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) returns a single value, not an array. Change your query to this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount FROM `receipts` WHERE category = :cat_id
```

and

```
echo money_format('%(#10n', $result['amount']).' CAD';
```

to

```
echo money_format('%(#10n', $result).' CAD';
```

Comment: Yep works. I did have SUM(amount) AS total, but I was returning ti as $result['total'] which was not rendering any data. So I assumed it had to be count.

Comment: If you had used `$data->fetch()` that would have worked with your original query, the value would have been in `$result['total']`